# login form calling soap webservices in android

Tags: android, mysql, android-intent

Hi i developed one login form calling soap webservices.it is success fully worked for me...But now i implement the one part.when my login details are successfully means it is go to next activity.
how is to do..here am facing some difficulties.
the coding part is below.

dis is my webservices java project:

```
package com.userlogin.ws;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Login {
public String authentication(String userName,String password){

String retrievedUserName = "";
String retrievedPassword = "";
String status = "";
try{

 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/androidlogin","root","");
 PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '"+userName+"'");
 ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

 while(result.next()){
retrievedUserName = result.getString("username");
retrievedPassword = result.getString("password");
}

if(retrievedUserName.equals(userName)&&retrievedPassword.equals(password)){
status = "Success!";

 }

 else{
 status = "Login fail!!!";
 }

 }
 catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return status;

  }

  }
```

dis is my android side coding part:

```
package com.androidlogin.ws;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AndroidLoginExampleActivity extends Activity {
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.userlogin.com";
private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8085/Login/services/Login?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.userlogin.com/authentication";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "authentication";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   public void onClick(View arg0) {
   loginAction();

   }
  });
   }

private void loginAction(){
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
    String user_Name = userName.getText().toString();
    EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
    String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

  //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
    unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
    unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

  //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
    passwordProp.setName("password");
    passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
    passwordProp.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(passwordProp);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
           SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

           TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
           result.setText(response.toString());

    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }

    Button registerScreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    // Listening to register new account link
    registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Switching to Register screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
      });
   }

   }
```

Here when am clicked button means it is redirect to next activity..but i wish to need if successful login means it is go to next activity....please where is putting dis intent coding or tell me how is to do...please guide me .

Comment: Hello, you have put intent in button click so it will move to next activity directly. But what you need to do is that once user enter password and username and click on submit you need to check with your web service. When u r calling your web service you will start progress dialog. once you get success message from your web service check it and allow to go to next activity... Hope this will help you

Comment: thank you...dis information is useful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, You have to **check the response form your login web service** call and make a condition on that base.

If your response contains **Success!** status then start **NewActivity** else show Login Failure `Dialog` or `Toast`.

**For Example:**

your logic should goes here for start new Activity,

```
try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        String status = response.toString();

        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
        result.setText(response.toString());

    if(status.equals("Success!"))
     {
       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
       startActivity(i);    
     }
    else
     {
         // Code for Login failure 
     }
   }
    catch(Exception e){
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to do Web Service invocation from inside AsynTask Class rather than from inside onCreate() since background operations should not affect UI thread.

What is [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)?

AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

Create a class inherted from AsyncTask and provide definition for onPreExecute, onPostExecute, onProgressUpdate and doInBackground methods inside main Activity class:

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Call Web Method
        loginStatus = WebService.invokeLoginWS(editTextUsername,editTextPassword,"authenticateUser");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    //Once WebService returns response
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //Make Progress Bar invisible
        webservicePG.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Intent intObj = new Intent(CheckLoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
        //Error status is false
        if(!errored){
            //Based on Boolean value returned from WebService
            if(loginStatus){
                //Navigate to Home Screen
                startActivity(intObj);
            }else{
                //Set Error message
                statusTV.setText("Login Failed, try again");
            }
        //Error status is true  
        }else{
            statusTV.setText("Error occured in invoking webservice");
        }
        //Re-initialize Error Status to False
        }

    @Override
    //Make Progress Bar visible
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        webservicePG.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

}

Call execute method of AsyncTask to initiate Web Service call.

```
//Create instance for AsyncCallWS
AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
//Call execute 
task.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  This code is Beneficial for you
> ```

```
   btnsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);        
             //Use this to add parameters
             request.addProperty("username",Username.getText().toString());
             request.addProperty("Password",password.getText().toString());

            //Declare the version of the SOAP request
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            try {
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);
                // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); 
                Log.e("result", "responce"+result);
                SoapObject root = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);
                Log.e("root", "responce"+root);
                System.out.println("********Count : "+ root.getPropertyCount());
                //value=new ArrayList<Detailinfo>();
                 for (int i = 0; i < root.getPropertyCount(); i++) 
                  {
                  SoapObject root1 = (SoapObject) root.getProperty(i);
                  Log.e("root1", "responce"+root1);
                     Detailinfo info=new Detailinfo();

                     info.setResponseCode(root1.getProperty("ResponseCode").toString());
                     Log.e("code", ""+root1.getProperty("ResponseCode").toString());
                     info.setResponseMessage( root1.getProperty("ResponseMessage").toString());
                     Log.e("msg", ""+root1.getProperty("ResponseCode").toString());

                 if(st1==Integer.parseInt(root1.getProperty("ResponseCode").toString()))
                     {
                     SoapObject root2 = (SoapObject) root1.getProperty(2); 
                     info.setCustomerID( root2.getProperty("CustomerID").toString());
                     info.setCustomerNumber( root2.getProperty("CustomerNumber").toString());
                     info.setLoginID( root2.getProperty("LoginID").toString());
                     info.setName(root2.getProperty("Name").toString());
                     info.setProfileImage( root2.getProperty("ProfileImage").toString());
                     info.setMobile( root2.getProperty("MobileNo").toString());
                     info.setEmailID( root2.getProperty("EmailID").toString());
                     info.setAccountType( root2.getProperty("AccountType").toString());
                     Log.e("AccountType", "responce"+root2.getProperty("AccountType").toString());
                      //for maintain session 
                   session.createUserLoginSession(info.getCustomerID(),info.getName(),info.getMobile(),info.getEmailID(),info.getAccountType());
                    // value.add(info);
                   Log.e("session"," "+session.toString());
                     Intent inten=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AccordionActivity.class);
                      startActivity(inten);
                  }
                 else
                 {

                 }
                }    
             } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
    });
```